# position:absolute reduces width in IE7

Tags: width, css-position, internet-explorer-7, css

I'm trying to position a div inside a div.
the outer div has a fixed width and heigt, the inner div contains some text, has a fixed height and automatically fits to the width of the outer div (default behavior, without "width: 100%").

When I now add position:relative to the outer div and position:absolute + bottom: 0 to the inner div, I just want the inner div to move to the bottom of the outer div, but keep the same width it had before. This works fine in most browsers (Internet Explorer 8+, Firefox, Opera), but in IE7 it reduces the width to fit the text inside the inner div.

Is there a clean and valid way to prevent this different behaviour in IE7?

You can see an example here: http://www.loud.fm/tmp (I'm talking about the black box at the inner bottom of the featured-slider-box.) Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your already using absolute positioning to lock it to the bottom why not add

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

to your CSS as well.

Comment: This worked. Thank you! I expected something like "display: block;" to help, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform `position: absolute`, you are breaking some of the relationship. In the example you mention, you'll notice that div of the black box belongs to an li element in which the li element has a static width set (of 590px). You could dynamically set the width of the inner div to that of the outer by using javascript on load to handle all situations.  Otherwise, set a static width size that matches that of the parent.

Comment: That would be a workaround, but it would mean that I either had to use additional JS (which I don't want to, if it's not absolutely necessary) or set a fixed width (which means that I have to change it manually, if I change the parent's width). It'd not what I'd call a clean solution for compensating the misbehavior of IE7. But thanks for your contribution, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had a pretty similar issue with Div's being changed in width by IE7.  A simple style tag solved it for me:

```
min-width: 100%;
```

After hours of trial and error, this was all it took.  Hope it helps!